# RadGrid ItemDataBound Event Causes Another Event to be Ignored

Tags: asp.net, event-handling, telerik, radgrid

I have a user control that contains a RadGrid and a RadToolBar control (below).

```
<telerik:RadToolBar ID="RadToolBar1" runat="server" Skin="Web20" style="width:100%;" OnButtonClick="RadToolBar1_ButtonClick">
    <Items>
        <telerik:RadToolBarButton ImageUrl="~/[path_omitted]/SaveRadToolBar1.png" Text="Save" ToolTip="Save" />
    </Items>
</telerik:RadToolBar>


<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" Skin="Vista" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource"> 
    <MasterTableView CommandItemDisplay="None" Height="30" DataKeyNames="ID" ClientDataKeyNames="ID" GroupLoadMode="Client" NoMasterRecordsText="You do not have any data"> 
        <GroupByExpressions> 
            <telerik:GridGroupByExpression> 
                <GroupByFields> 
                    <telerik:GridGroupByField FieldName="Topic.Category.Name" /> 
                </GroupByFields> 
                <SelectFields> 
                    <telerik:GridGroupByField FieldName="Topic.Category.Name" HeaderText="Category" /> 
                </SelectFields> 
            </telerik:GridGroupByExpression> 
        </GroupByExpressions> 

        <Columns> 
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" UniqueName="DataID" Visible="false" />
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Topic.ID" UniqueName="DataTopicID" Visible="false" />
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Topic.Category.Name" HeaderText="Name" UniqueName="DataCategoryName" Visible="false" /> 
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Topic.Name" HeaderText="Topic" UniqueName="DataTopicName" /> 
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Go" UniqueName="DataGoTo" HeaderStyle-Width="50"> 
                <ItemTemplate> 
                    <asp:Button ID="ButtonGoTo" runat="server" ToolTip="Go to data" Text="Go" /> 
                </ItemTemplate> 
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn> 
        </Columns> 
    </MasterTableView> 
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

The RadToolBar ButtonClick event inits a postback to save the contents of the page (the page contains other controls such as drop down list , text box, etc. but none are related to the issue I am having). With the above code everything works as expected (the RadToolBar ButtonClick event handler get called and the content on the page is saved).

The problem occurs when I add an event handler for the RadGrid's ItemDataBound event (see below).

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" Skin="Vista" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource" OnItemDataBound="RadGrid1_ItemDataBound"> 
    <MasterTableView CommandItemDisplay="None" Height="30" DataKeyNames="ID" ClientDataKeyNames="ID" GroupLoadMode="Client" NoMasterRecordsText="You do not have any data"> 
        <GroupByExpressions> 
            <telerik:GridGroupByExpression> 
                <GroupByFields> 
                    <telerik:GridGroupByField FieldName="Topic.Category.Name" /> 
                </GroupByFields> 
                <SelectFields> 
                    <telerik:GridGroupByField FieldName="Topic.Category.Name" HeaderText="Category" /> 
                </SelectFields> 
            </telerik:GridGroupByExpression> 
        </GroupByExpressions> 

        <Columns> 
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" UniqueName="DataID" Visible="false" />
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Topic.ID" UniqueName="DataTopicID" Visible="false" />
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Topic.Category.Name" HeaderText="Name" UniqueName="DataCategoryName" Visible="false" /> 
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Topic.Name" HeaderText="Topic" UniqueName="DataTopicName" /> 
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Go" UniqueName="DataGoTo" HeaderStyle-Width="50"> 
                <ItemTemplate> 
                    <asp:Button ID="ButtonGoTo" runat="server" ToolTip="Go to data" Text="Go" /> 
                </ItemTemplate> 
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn> 
        </Columns> 
    </MasterTableView> 
</telerik:RadGrid> 

protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (e.Item is GridDataItem) 
    { 
        GridDataItem dataItem = e.Item as GridDataItem; 
        (dataItem["DataGoTo"].FindControl("ButtonGoTo") as Button) 
            .PostBackUrl = String.Format( 
                "~/ShowData.aspx?id={0}", 
                dataItem["DataTopicID"].Text); 
    } 
}
```

I use this handler to set the PostBackUrl of an Button control (I do it on this event because I need the ID of the RadGrid's row content). The problem is that the RadToolBar ButtonClick event handler doesn't get called anymore.

With everything working, the event sequence is: Load -> NeedDataSource -> ButtonClick. After adding the ItemDataBound event the sequence is Load -> NeedDataSource -> ItemDataBound (the ButtonClick event gets "ignored").

Why does adding the ItemDataBound event in the RadGrid affect the ButtonClick event in the RadToolBar? How can I get the ButtonClick event to "not be ignored" while still maintaining the ItemDataBound event?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to surround RadGrid1_ItemDataBound by try/catch-block.

Comment: Thanks but my issue isn't with the event handler RadGrid1_ItemDataBound. My issue is that the RadToolBar ButtonClick event handler (not shown) is not getting hit.

Answer (score 0):

1. there is no `onClick =" yourHandlerName "` for your buttonclick event to get fired.
2. you can use telerik `GridButtonColumn` column and set `CommandName = "DoDomething"` and fire it in the `OnItemCommand="Grid1_ItemCommand` eventhandler of your grid.